# Correctly set global variable from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I have the simple code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var dataFromBrowser;
var dataForStore = [];

var callServerOwnerId = { 
  callback:callbackFunction, 
  arg: dataFromBrowser 
};
// call to DWR function - from Java
AssetScreener.getEntityOwnerIds(callServerOwnerId);


function callbackFunction(dataFromServer, arg1) {
 // yes, I see what I need
 alert(dataFromServer);
 return dataForStore[0] = dataFromServer[0];

}



console.log(dataForStore);
```

The problem is that I need to retrieve data from my `callbackFunction` and set data to `dataForStore` ?

Comment: You don't need the "return", just dataForStore[0] = dataFromServer[0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript setting a global variable is as simple as ommitting the var keyword.

For example:

```
 var someVar = 5

 function foo(){
      someVar = someVar + 1;
 }
```

Will produce undefined while

```
 someVar = 5;

 function foo(){

      someVar = someVar+1;
 }
```

Will produce 6. Note that generally speaking (there are of course exceptions), if you're using global variables you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the var before dataForStore , and it will become a global variable.